# Inserting Image using Class in Python 3.3.1

Tags: image, class, canvas, python-3.x, grid

I am trying to insert an image(logo) in GIUs to display it in top left corner using grid and preferable in frame.
When I do this code without demonstrator then it works perfectly but as soon I put it in Demonstrator the image disappears. Any Suggestion?

```
class TaskGUI():
    def __init__(self,master):
        header    = Frame(master, )
        header.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W)
        canvas= Canvas(header, bg= 'pink')
        Label(header, bg= 'blue' ).grid(row=1)
        canvas.grid(row=1,column=1)
        imgLogo = PhotoImage(file = 'logo.gif' )
        canvas.create_image(10,10, image= imgLogo, ancho= NW)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    top =Tk()
    top.geometry('10920x1080')
    top.title("Stel")
    top.grid()

    app = TaskGUI(top)

    top.mainloop()
```

I tried to use PIL libary but could not find any solution on this on either, I get this error:

```
    from PIL import  Image,ImageTk
File "C:\Program Files\Python\PIL\Image.py", line 57
    except ImportError, v:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to run the code using Python 3 but PIL is only compatible with Python 2.

In Python 3 the syntax to catch an exception is `except ImportError as v` while it used to be `except ImportError, v` in Python 2. Note that changing this most likely won't help since there will be many other incompatible things within PIL.

**However, [Pillow](http://python-imaging.github.io/) is a compatible fork of PIL that is compatible with Python 3.**

Comment: Thanks now my pillow is working. I also find out why it does not display image when I am using class. My correction was to put << self.imgLogo >> Then it works.